# Storing packets in intervals using Omnet++

Tags: timer, scheduling, omnet++

I am a new user of omnet++ and I´d like to know if someone can help me to create the following function: on an intermediate and forwarder node I need to store the amount of packets arriving for 10ms and for next 10ms not storing and again for 10ms store and so on. Thank´s.